# React Components and Local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am working on a reactJS project and I want to transfer the data searched(filtered) from one page to another. I used local storage to help me with this. first I make a req in db and get the wanted houses, after I save them in local storage. in another component in the search page I set the state values from local storage.[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XA9p.png)
I have 2 problems with this:

1. I made it so when search button is clicked in home page after setting the filtered data in local storage to redirect to search page but for some reason it shows me "Cannot read property 'map' of null"
2. In use effect I made an if condition to check if data in local storage exits or not. if it doesn't make a get req to show all data and set it to local storage so can search later(not very important right now)
   if I reload the page it works fine but the state has the old values
   I tried debugging but I couldn't find the problem

```js
//this is the search button 
   
<div className="search-btn-container">
          <Link to="/rent">
            <button
              className="item2-search-button"
              onClick={() => {
                search(price.min, price.max, location, parseInt(rooms, 10));
              }}
            >
              Search
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>

//this is the display component
   
export default function Search component(match) {
  const [homes, setHomes] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchedApi"))
  );
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("searchedApi") === undefined) {
      axios
        .get("/link")
        .then((res) => {
          const info = res.data;
          setHomes(res.data);
          localStorage.setItem("searchedApi", res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="homes-component">
      <div className="homes-component-content">
        <form action="" className="homes-component-select">
          <label htmlFor="sort">Sort By: </label>
          <select name="sort" id="sort">
            <option value="Price">Price</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <div className="homes-grid">
          {loading ? (
            <LoadingCard />
          ) : (
            homes.map((home) => {
              return (
                <div className="homes-grid-item" key={home._id}>
                  {home.premium ? (
                    <img className="premium-logo" src={IMG1} alt="" />
                  ) : (
                    <></>
                  )}
                  <img className="homes-grid-img" src={home.img} alt="lol" />

                  <div
                    className={
                      home.premium
                        ? "home-item-info home-sub-Prem"
                        : "home-item-info home-sub-Norm"
                    }
                  >
                    <p>
                      <img src={IMG} alt="" />
                      Rruga: {home.adress.rruga}
                    </p>
                    {home.description}
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: LocalStorage only avaiable when page rendered. So you should use it inside the useEffect. Change your code `const [homes, setHomes] = useState([]);` and add `setHomes(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchedApi")))` inside useEffect

Comment: I tried it but still it doesn't work

Comment: Why using localStorage to pass data from one component to another? Why don't you use `props`?

Comment: i think this is the best idea(i am just a junior developer) because the button is inside a child component of the first page and the component where i want to show the data is in a child of search page . so i thought this is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit the `useEffect` and you need to call the local storage inside of it

your code will be like :

```
export default function Search component(match) {
  const [homes, setHomes] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("searchedApi") === undefined) {
      axios
        .get("/link")
        .then((res) => {
          const info = res.data;
          setHomes(res.data);
          localStorage.setItem("searchedApi", res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      // if there is data in local storage 
      setHomes(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchedApi")))
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
// the rest of the code ...
```